# Bash script - How to preserve new line character passed to bash function?

Tags: bash, shell, variables

I have two files:

```
touch a.txt
touch b.txt
```

In bash I would like to list them each one in its own line.

```
#!/bin/bash
var=$(ls -1 *.txt)
echo "$var"
```

Because there are double quotes in: echo "$var" command each of file is displayed in separate lines (that is what I want):

```
a.txt
b.txt
```

Now to the problem. If I add function:

```
#!/bin/bash
function fun_cmd () {
     $1
}
var=$(ls -1 *.txt)
fun_cmd "echo $var"
```

and echo command displays them in one single line:

```
a.txt b.txt
```

In the last sample (function), I would like output to be displayed in two lines, just like first sample.

Comment: Passing (or storing) commands is difficult; read [BashFAQ #50: I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Always quote correctly!
- Don't use a single argument, but all argument of your function with `"$@"`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
function fun_cmd () {
     "$@"
}
var="$(ls -1 -- *txt)"
fun_cmd echo "$var"
```